# Is the viewmodel's livedata active in the entire app lifecycle or only in the activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a viewModel with a string variable as livedata.

I observe the livedata in ActivityOne and ActivityTwo using viewmodel.

As I set the value of livedata as "StateFlow" in ActivityOne using viewmodels function to set the value.

Then I start ActivityTwo, will the viewmodel's livedata will observe empty value or "StateFlow".

ViewModel :

class StateViewModel: ViewModel()
{

```
private var _h = MutableLiveData<String>()

private val h: LiveData<String> get() = _h


fun set(text: String)
{
    _h.value = text
}

fun get(): LiveData<String> = h
```

}

Comment: well, you could probably test it, right ?

Comment: I tested it, the value is live only in the opened activity. If I change and start another activity the value becomes empty?

Comment: probably because they're not actually the same view model, hard to tell without you posting code

Comment: Updated the question with viewModel codes